# How do I modify the new 4.6 CiviMail form?

Tags: civimail, extension, hooks, developer

I am the author of a CiviCRM extension that needs to disable, depending on configuration, the URL tracking and open tracking checkboxes of the mailing form. In version 4.4 this was accomplished using hook_civicrm_buildForm (CRM_Mailing_Form_Settings) and calling the freeze method on those elements.

This form hook is not getting called in version 4.6, so how would I go about doing this now?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: You might want to look at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9062/how-to-change-mailing-form-and-set-the-default-value-for-url-tracking-to-false and http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/adding-dynamic-data-in-civimail-angular-template

Answer (score 3):

I ended up adding a small bit of javascript that waits for Angular to build the form, then it disables the checkboxes. Don't know if it's the right way, but it works.

```
CRM.$(function($) {

function disable_tracking() {
    var i = $('#tab-tracking').length;

    if (i > 0) {
        $('input[name="url_tracking"]').attr('disabled', true);
        $('input[name="open_tracking"]').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else setTimeout(disable_tracking, 250);
}

if ( (typeof(CRM.crmMailing) == 'object') && (CRM.vars.sendgrid.track_optional == '0') )
    disable_tracking();
```

})

Comment: Possible to share the JS code here? We are stuck with a similar problem and your code might help. Thanks

Comment: Just added the code to my answer. Hope it helps.