# Change default for tracking options to "no"

Tags: civimail

In some use cases, we rarely or never want wo use the tracking features of CiviCRM.

Therefore, I would have like to default the tracking option to uncheck "Track Click Throughs" and "Track Opens".

Can I put an option into civicrm.settings.php (or maybe somewhere else) to achieve that?

Comment: Related question here http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9062/change-mailing-form/9106