# Civimail New Mailing; "Track Click Throughs" and "Track Opens" off by default.

Tags: civimail

When doing a new mailing, you can choose "Track Click Throughs" and 
"Track Opens". These are on by default. Is it possible to set them off by default?

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look here http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9062/how-to-change-mailing-form-and-set-the-default-value-for-url-tracking-to-false

Comment: Does Andrei's comment answer your question?

Comment: It might do - I will have a look at writing an extension soon and try it! Did see reply, just haven't had time yet.