# CiviMail: How to make url tracking not default?

Tags: civimail, default-settings

We're using CiviCRM 4.7.15 and want to uncheck the url tracking checkboxes in CiviMail per default. Disabling them by pure JS/jQuery is a bit hacky due to the fact that CiviMail uses angular. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: See both answers here http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/9062/872 it covers both JS/JQuery and AngularJs

Comment: Jesus, I checked for questions answering this. Sorry and thank you. Do you want to provide your comment as an answer?

Comment: Probably better to close this question and upvote the existing question/answers? :)