# Append an option to the BlockSchedule Directive in crmMailing

Tags: civimail, developer, angular

I'm making a first foray into customizing the mailing compose screen.

I want to add a third option to the options in BlockSchedule.html (schedule.mode = regular) which will open up a few more options to allow you to send mailings on a regular basis.

The template code I want to add is along the lines of

```
<div>
  <input ng-model="schedule.mode" type="radio" name="send" value="recur" id="schedule-send-recur"/>
  <label for="schedule-send-recur">{{ts('Send on a regular basis')}}</label>
</div>
```

Selecting this will open up a new directive with options for sending on a regular basis. It will also swap the submit mailing button for a schedule mailings button and possibly do other stuff.

But right now, I am stuck on a good way to add this option.

[This answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10391) (adapted below) makes me think that something along the lines of the following would work, but what do I do with the directive at this point?!

```
angular.module('crmMailing').config(function($provide){
   // intercept crmMailingBlockMailing directive, note the 'Directive' suffix
   $provide.decorator('crmMailingBlockScheduleDirective', function($delegate){
        var directive = $delegate[0];
```

Comment: Let me know if there's anything unclear, happy to help!

Comment: FYI, I ended up writing [this angular code](https://github.com/3sd/civicrm-recurring-mail/blob/master/ang/civicrm-recurring-mail.js) that works alongside  [this template](https://github.com/3sd/civicrm-recurring-mail/blob/master/ang/crmMailingRecurSchedule.html) and also adds [this extra scheduling option](https://github.com/3sd/civicrm-recurring-mail/blob/master/ang/crmMailingBlockScheduleRecurOption.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do now is *decorate* the directive ;)

The decorator method allows you to *decorate/modify* an angular directive/service/factory/controller before its usage/instantiated.

You have two options (that I know of) to manipulate the directives DOM, one is the [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile-) function, used for template DOM manipulation (is where the template is actually compiled), and the second is the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-) function, is where the data/scope is attached to the instantiated element/elements, and usaully used for event listeneres, like $watch

The angular mailing app uses a boilerplate template to declare directives, see the source [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/ang/crmMailing/services.js#L530).

I'll try to explain with inline comments:

```
angular.module( 'crmMailing' ).config( function( $provide ){

        // the callback recieves the directive when the Mailing app bootsraps
        $provide.decorator( 'crmMailingBlockScheduleDirective', function( $delegate ){

            // $delegate is an array, we grab and store the directive into the 'directive' variable
            var directive = $delegate[0];

            // we hold the original link function 
            var link = directive.link;

            // as the link function is already defined in Civi's boilerplate
            // we create the compile function and return a new link function calling apply on the old link function
            directive.compile = function( Element, Attrs ){

                // you can manipulate the directive's template here, like adding your own DOM elements/directives
                Element.append( '<h1>Text added from compile</h1>' );

                // return new link function
                return function( scope, elem, attr ){

                    // call apply to get original functionality
                    link.apply( this, arguments );

                    // add new functionality here
                    elem.append( '<h1>Text added from new link function</h1>' );

                };
            };

            // always return $delegate
            return $delegate;
        }); 
    });
```

In order for this to work what I do is declare a fake/empty angular module like `crmMailSubjectReview = angular.module( 'crmMailSubjectReview', [] );`, load it via `hook_civicrm_angularModules` and then add the `crmMailing` config block, see [here](https://gist.github.com/mecachisenros/834e8a38cf4204a5e4d554b471f1f2cf) another small example (have a look at the comments to see the template and the end result).

Comment: Thanks for this, Andrei. I have your code example above working. I'm trying to work out when I might use the first example `Element.append()` and when I might try and use the last `Elem.append`. Any ideas? Or should I not worry about it.

Comment: You usually want to use `compile` (`Element.append()`), specially if you are appending directives, if you try to append a directive in `link` it won't work, as the current directive/element and its children at that point are already instantiated. `link` will render "normal" DOM elements but not angular elements. You could use the `$compile` service injecting it in `link` and then do something like `var myDirective = '<div my-directive></div>'; var compiledEl = $compile(myDirective)($scope); elem.append(compiledEl);` but I think you'll probably run into issues with this approach

Comment: In summary, when using `compile` you are dealing with template DOM elements (angular elements) and when using `link` you are dealing with _jQuery-ish_ elements that can be manipulated based on scope and attributes, if that makes sense

Comment: Thanks - getting there now - will post a link to what i did soon (just polishing slightly) in case that is useful for people...

Comment: Hey Andrei - in case you're interested, I posted my angular code above.